# Get model attribute from other class in same model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

How do I get value of another class in the same model?
Can I also use properties?
I want to use Finance.net_income and Finance.net_margin inside the Stats Class. I tried searching for an anwser but I couldnt find it, I am also new to django.

```
class Stats(models.Model):
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shares_outstanding = models.FloatField(default=0)  

    @property
    def earnings_per_share(self):
        ####### ISSUE IS HERE #####
        return Finance.net_income / self.shares_outstanding

class Finance(models.Model):
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_revenue = models.FloatField(default=0) 
    operating_income = models.FloatField(default=0) 
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    net_income = models.FloatField(default=0) 
    cash = models.FloatField(default=0) 
    total_debt = models.FloatField(default=0) 

    @property
    def operating_margin(self):
        if self.total_revenue:
            now = (self.operating_income / self.total_revenue)*100
        else:
            now = 0
        return now

    @property
    def net_margin(self):
        if self.total_revenue:
            now = (self.net_income / self.total_revenue)*100
        else:
            now = 0
        return now
```

Comment: How is a `Stats` object related toa `Finance` object here?

Comment: inside the `property` `earnings_per_share` you need to get an instance of the model `Finance` and all be fine.

Comment: Both Classes are in the same model

Comment: How would I get an instance in it then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@property
def earnings_per_share(self):
   total_earnings_per_share = 0 
   for finance in self.stock.finance_set.all():
         total_earnings_per_share += finance.net_income / self.shares_outstanding
   return total_earnings_per_share
```

Well, you will not get a single instance of Finance, because it is Foreign Key between Finance and Stock, meaning one stock can have multiple finance.

Comment: Perfect, how would I get the latest finance? sorted by date

Comment: Yes, use `order_by("-date")[0]` :) Or use [latest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#latest)

Answer (score 1):

Given you want to calculate the *sum* of the `Finance`s with the same `Stock` as the `Stock` of the `Stat`s object, you can calculate this with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

@property
def earnings_per_share(self):
    return Finance.objects.filter(
        stock_id=self.stock_id
    ).aggregate(
        total=Sum('net_income')
    )['total'] / self.shares_outstanding
```

or a more descriptive filter:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

@property
def earnings_per_share(self):
    return Finance.objects.filter(
        stock__stats=self
    ).aggregate(
        total=Sum('net_income')
    )['total'] / self.shares_outstanding
```

If no all `Stats` objects have one or more `Finance` objects, then the `Sum` will return `None` (`NULL`), in that case we probably want to return `0` instead. We can use the [**`Coalesce`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) function for this:

```
from django.db.models import Coalesce, Sum, Value

@property
def earnings_per_share(self):
    return Finance.objects.filter(
        stock__stats=self
    ).aggregate(
        total=Coalesce(Sum('net_income'), Value(0))
    )['total'] / self.shares_outstanding
```